# How to pre-set cursor or selection for default answer in input dialog

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

If one creates an inputdialog with `inputdlg` and a default answer, it looks like that:

[image]

Which callback command do I need to make it look like that?

[image]

The documentation is missing a lot here. It's a kind of "luxury service" for the customer ;)
But I think it would be nice, if it's easy to implement.

---

This question is actually solved, as I found out that there are convenient functions like `uigetfile` and `uiputfile` for my particular case. But the general case of my questions remains unsolved or at least I haven't tested the java approach.

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid using the builtin `inputdlg` without changes this is not possible.
At least there's not 'hidden' feature allowing for this.

You'd need access to the underlying java TextField object for that purpose.
You could copy `inputdlg` to some new place and make your own version of it.

In combination with the `findjobj` utility the desired functionality in principle exists.
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects
Things could look like this then:

```
% create the edit-field:
h = uicontrol('style', 'edit',...);
% get the underlying java object
% this should be a javahandle to a JTextField
jtextfield = findjobj(h);
% set start/end of the selection as desired:
jtextfield.setSelectionStart(startPos);
jtextfield.setSelectionEnd(endPos);
```

Comment: `inputdlg` does not seem to work "standalone" and I cannot find the missing function `getnicedialoglocation` (nice name btw.). However it seems quite fiddly just to get a little bit of more functionality. I think it's not worth it and I'll postpone it. Thank you anyway!

Comment: You could find that function in `<matlabroot>/toolbox/matlab/uitools/private`. However you're probably right, its not really worth it if it's only a "nice-to-have"...