# Matlab: Automatically place cursor in an Edit text box at start

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I would like to place the cursor (or even better highlight the text) in an Edit text box in a Matlab GUI when the application starts, is there any simple way of doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: simple way: no. maybe possible workaround: [I once had a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19399701/how-to-pre-set-cursor-or-selection-for-default-answer-in-input-dialog)

Comment: @thewaywewalk i just found something, that could help: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/80041#204096

Comment: ok, not possible to use with newer version of matlab :(

Answer (score 1):

You'll need this tool from Yair Altman
http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14317-findjobj-find-java-handles-of-matlab-graphic-objects

and than just type following:

```
jEdit = findjobj(HandleOfYourEditBox);
jEdit.Caret.setDot(0)
```

To highlight text use following:

```
jEdit.selectAll % to highlight everything
jEdit.setSelectionStart(3) % start Index
jEdit.setSelectionEnd(4)  % end Index
```